# How can I get the (video) activities of a user with the YouTube API v3 in Java

Tags: java, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am using Java to get the activities of an authenticated User (OAuth2.0).
The Problem is, I am not getting the result I want. If I am visiting youtube.com and look at the activities (http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions) there are a lot of videos.

If I am fetching the videos with
`YouTube.Activities.List request = youtube.activities().list("snippet");`

`request.setHome(true);`
`request.setMaxResults(50L);`

I get videos that are more than 10 hours old, even if there were 10 new videos in the last 2 hours. The feed I am getting is not very new... And I am only getting 24 entries, even if the maximum setting is on 50. With the old YouTube Api (v2) I am getting more than 100 responses.

Is this just buggy and not working, or am I making mistakes?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as simple as stupid:
It's not possible to fetch the subscription videos in v3 - we will have to use v2 to do that. That doesn't make sense, but google is the boss. "Activities" are meant as Videos you should watch. Yeah I know...

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of bug reports please [file it in public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29) if it's not filed by someone else already. Stackoverflow is for coding questions.

Filed the report internally, if you can create a bug in public tracker, you can keep track of it.